# Remove item from the list dynamically if there are no child elements

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 3 array lists as below:

```
 groups = [ { grpId: 1, grpName: "Vegetables" }, { grpId: 2, grpName: "Fruits" }, { grpId: 3, grpName: "Staples" }];
 subGrp = [ { subGrpId: "V1", grpId: 1, subGrpName: "Carrot" }, { subGrpId: "F1", grpId: 2, subGrpName: "Apple" },
            { subGrpId: "S1", grpId: 3, subGrpName: "Dal" }];
 quantity = [ { quantityValue: "1kg", subGrpId: "V1" }, { quantityValue: "1kg", subGrpId: "S1" }];
```

**Condition:** If there aren't any "quantity" related to "subGrp" Array, then we need to remove the whole entry from the custom list.

Using above array lists, I am trying to build a **custom list** as below:

```
const grpSet = new Set(this.groups.map(i => ({ id: i.grpId, name: i.grpName }))); 
grpSet.forEach(g =>
  this.groceryList.push({
    grp: g["name"],
    grpTypeList: this.subGrp.filter(el => {
      if (el.grpId === g["id"] && this.quantity) {
        el["quantities"] = this.quantity.filter(
          v => v.subGrpId === el["subGrpId"]
        );
        if (el["quantities"].length > 0) {
          return el;
        }
      }
    })
  })
);

// above logic will lead us to below custom list.
```

From this, I need to remove Fruits entry since grpTypeList is empty. But my logic is not allowing me to do it.

```
[{
    "grp": "Vegetables",
    "grpTypeList": [{
        "subGrpId": "V1",
        "grpId": 1,
        "subGrpName": "Carrot",
        "quantities": [{
                "quantityValue": "1kg",
                "subGrpId": "V1"
            },
            {
                "quantityValue": "2kg",
                "subGrpId": "V1"
            }
        ]
    }]
},
// remove this complete object as grpTypeList is empty
{
    "grp": "Fruits",
    "grpTypeList": [

    ]
}, 
{
    "grp": "Staples",
    "grpTypeList": [{
        "subGrpId": "S1",
        "grpId": 3,
        "subGrpName": "Dal",
        "quantities": [{
            "quantityValue": "1kg",
            "subGrpId": "S1"
        }]
    }]
} ]
```

Using above list, I am plotting my html to display as below figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are just minor changes that you need to take care of,
Please update your code with the below lines:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  groceryList = [];
  groups = [
    { grpId: 1, grpName: "Vegetables" },
    { grpId: 2, grpName: "Fruits" },
    { grpId: 3, grpName: "Staples" }
  ];
  subGrp = [
    { subGrpId: "V1", grpId: 1, subGrpName: "Carrot" },
    { subGrpId: "F1", grpId: 2, subGrpName: "Apple" },
    { subGrpId: "S1", grpId: 3, subGrpName: "Dal" }
  ];
  quantity = [
    { quantityValue: "1kg", subGrpId: "V1" },
    { quantityValue: "2kg", subGrpId: "V1" },
    { quantityValue: "1kg", subGrpId: "S1" }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.groceryList = [];
    const grpSet = new Set(
      this.groups.map(i => ({ id: i.grpId, name: i.grpName }))
    );

    grpSet.forEach(g =>{
      let element:any[];
      element= this.subGrp.filter(el => {
          if (el.grpId === g["id"] && this.quantity) {
            el["quantities"] = this.quantity.filter(
              v => v.subGrpId === el["subGrpId"]
            );
            if (el["quantities"].length > 0) {
              return el;
            }
          }
        })
        if(element && element.length){
        this.groceryList.push({
          grp:g["name"],
          grpTypeList:element
        })
        }
    }
    );
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.groceryList));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Minal, I feel my logic is bit large to arrive at my custom list. Is there any other ways to shorten the code and make it little fast in newer ways?

Comment: There are other ways too, but they would not make much difference. As you have to make completely different type of object by filtering three array, it would take same time and space. This approach looks good enough.

Comment: By replacing your code, you can make the array as per your requirement.